# Geodesic submersion on the orthogonal complement of kernel

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

I found this assertion while reading a paper:

Since $F$ is a Riemannian submersion, we have
$(\nabla F_*)(Z_1,Z_2)=0$ (F is geodesic map) for $Z_1, Z_2\in \Gamma((KerF_*)^\perp).$

Here $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection. What would be the proof of this, I cannot understand?

Comment: What do you mean by $F$ is geodesic? so $F: I\to M$ and $I$ is an interval?

Comment: The above condition defines totally geodesic map, meaning the second fundamental form $(\nabla F_*)(X,Y)=0$. $F:M\to N$, where $M$ and $N$ are Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: Is that common to define totally geodesic map of a submersion?

Comment: Actually this submersion is called totally geodesic one. The same way you have totally geodesic submanifold.